# How do I initialize the CMCalibratedMagneticField property so that it does not return zero?

Tags: ios6, calibration, magnetometer

This question has been asked before 
[CMCalibratedMagneticField doesn't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282902/cmcalibratedmagneticfield-doesnt-update)
but it wasn't really answered. I am very lost on this one.

I'm using a simple formulation, but field.field.x, y, z are always zero.

```
if (motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable)
{
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]  
                                       withHandler:
       ^(CMDeviceMotion *motionData, NSError *error) {
           CMCalibratedMagneticField field = motionData.magneticField;
           NSLog(@"x: %f  y:%f  z:%f", field.field.x
                                     , field.field.y
                                     , field.field.z);

    }];       
}
```

Sample output is

```
2013-07-14 22:18:27.865 TestApp[6678:907] x: 0.000000  y:0.000000  z:0.000000

2013-07-14 22:18:27.869 TestApp[6678:907] x: 0.000000  y:0.000000  z:0.000000

2013-07-14 22:18:27.879 TestApp[6678:907] x: 0.000000  y:0.000000  z:0.000000
```

I am pretty certain the issue is not the phone as the preceding answer suggested: I am coding for a fairly modern 4S. I have the CoreMotion, CoreLocation, and CoreData frameworks in place -- maybe there is a header file I don't know about that I need to import in the implementation? currently I only seem to need

```
#import <tgmath.h>
```

but that is for other stuff.

Any help would be appreciated!

Tim Redfield

Comment: oops -- that was import <tgmath.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
- (void)startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:(CMAttitudeReferenceFrame)referenceFrame 
                                            toQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue 
                                        withHandler:(CMDeviceMotionHandler)handler
```

with any of:

```
     CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical  
     CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical  
     CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical
```

but not:

```
     CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical
```

(another SO question you missed:[CoreMotion - magneticField is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556859/coremotion-magneticfield-is-always-0))

if you want too much information on magnetometer data, see my answer to this question:[In iOS, what is the difference between the Magnetic Field values from the Core Location and Core Motion frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380632/in-ios-what-is-the-difference-between-the-magnetic-field-values-from-the-core-l/15470571#15470571)

Comment: Thanks! This works. I had seen your other (very extensive, very informative!) posting but was not able to extract this syntax.